# How to auto scroll the text to bottom in TextFormField if it overflows in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dynamic, flutter-textformfield, flutter-scrollbar

I am using TextFormField to display the dynamic text. I am also using 'speech_to_text' plugin to convert the speech into text. Then the converted text is set in the TextFormField which is scrollable.

When i write in the TextformField its scrolling to bottom if the text overflows. But its not auto scrolling when setting the text from using dynamic variable like below;

```
  SingleChildScrollView(
                  controller: _scrollController2,
                  child: Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: 50,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: AppColors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0),
                    ),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      enabled: true,
                      controller: _textFromSpeechController2,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                              _scrollController2.animateTo(_scrollController2.position.maxScrollExtent,
                              duration: Duration(microseconds: 200),
                              curve:Curves.easeInOut );
                        });
                      },
                      maxLines: null,
                      expands: true,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                       
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 5, vertical: 5),
                      ),
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                    ),
             ),
         ),
```

speech_to_text

```
 late stt.SpeechToText _speech;
 String _speechText = '';
 String newText = "";

  Future<void> _listenForSpeech() async {
// print("_listenForSpeech called ");
if (isAvailable) {
  print("isAvailable 11 " + isAvailable.toString());
  bool isListening = await _speech.listen(
    onResult: (result) {
      setState(() {
        _isListening = true;
        newText = result.recognizedWords;
        _textFromSpeechController2.text = result.recognizedWords;
        // print("newText --- " + newText);
      });
    },
  );
  if (!isListening) {
    setState(() {
      _speechText = 'Failed to start listening';
    });
  }
} else {
  setState(() {
    _speechText = 'Speech recognition not available';
    print("not supported");
  });
 }
}
```

The speech_to_text is working fine and setting the text into the TextFormField. But the problem is that its not scrolling to the bottom automatically when the text is overflows.